# Take only the first (or nth) element after explode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is that possible to only take the first element after the explode() function?

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|dog                                      |
+-----------------------------------------+
|[[Max,Black],3]                          |
|[[Spot,White],2]                         |
|[[Michael,Yellow],1]                     |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

For example, in the above case we only want to keep [Max, Black], [Spot, white] and [Michael,Yellow]. The second elements in each cell (3, 2, and 1) can actually be discarded.

Thanks!

Comment: Can I use a `UDF` or is there a restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your schema looks something like this:

```
root
 |-- dog: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- col1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- col1: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- col2: integer (nullable = false)
```

Then you could do the following:

```
test.withColumn("dog", $"dog".getField("col1"))
```

Or if you wanted to keep both columns, do:

```
test.select($"dog", $"dog".getField("col1") as "dog2")
```

Comment: No, this is not what the OP had.  Note that he said he needed to *explode*, and that he showed an array-like strucure.  So he did not have `struct`s, but rather _arrays_.